# Jquery/Ajax not sending serialization data properly

Tags: jquery, laravel, serialization

I am developing a online exam module in which user will create question quantity. after that it will submit the form .... so we are sending the form data using form.serialize but in controller it is showing only last question input boxes data i have mentioned the code so when user click on submit it showing only question 2 data in controller. please how to retrieve all question data and store in database

```
   <div class="form-group  text-center col-md-12 custom-mt-form-group">
       <input type="text" name="ques" />
     <label class="control-label">Question 1</label><i class="bar"></i>
     <span class="err_name"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group  text-center col-md-4 custom-mt-form-group">
  <input type="text" name="opta" />
  <label class="control-label">Option A</label><i class="bar"></i>
   <span class="err_name"></span>
  </div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" class="mt-5">

   <div class="form-group  text-center col-md-4 custom-mt-form-group">
  <input type="text" name="optb" />
  <label class="control-label">Option B</label><i class="bar"></i>
   <span class="err_name"></span>
  </div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" class="mt-5">

    <div class="form-group  text-center col-md-4 custom-mt-form-group">
  <input type="text" name="optc" />
  <label class="control-label">Option C</label><i class="bar"></i>
   <span class="err_name"></span>
  </div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" class="mt-5">

    <div class="form-group  text-center col-md-4 custom-mt-form-group">
  <input type="text" name="optd" />
  <label class="control-label">Option D</label><i class="bar"></i>
   <span class="err_name"></span>
  </div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" class="mt-5">

      <!-- Start Next Question-->

    <div class="form-group  text-center col-md-12 custom-mt-form-group">
       <input type="text" name="ques" />
     <label class="control-label">Question 2</label><i class="bar"></i>
     <span class="err_name"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group  text-center col-md-4 custom-mt-form-group">
  <input type="text" name="opta" />
  <label class="control-label">Option A</label><i class="bar"></i>
   <span class="err_name"></span>
  </div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" class="mt-5">

   <div class="form-group  text-center col-md-4 custom-mt-form-group">
  <input type="text" name="optb" />
  <label class="control-label">Option B</label><i class="bar"></i>
   <span class="err_name"></span>
  </div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" class="mt-5">

    <div class="form-group  text-center col-md-4 custom-mt-form-group">
  <input type="text" name="optc" />
  <label class="control-label">Option C</label><i class="bar"></i>
   <span class="err_name"></span>
  </div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" class="mt-5">

    <div class="form-group  text-center col-md-4 custom-mt-form-group">
  <input type="text" name="optd" />
  <label class="control-label">Option D</label><i class="bar"></i>
   <span class="err_name"></span>
  </div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" class="mt-5">

    <div class="form-group col-md-3 text-center ">
    <button class="btn btn-primary ad_qs" type="button">Submit</button>
   <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="reset">Cancel</button>
     </div>
```

Jquery Code

```
       $(".ad_qs").click(function(){

                var qs=$("#eq_form").serialize();
                alert(qs);

                $.ajax({
               headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        },
                        url:'/add-ques',
                        type:'post',
                        data:qs,
                        success:function(data){

                            if(data.success){
                                //alert("done");
                                $(".scs_msg").fadeIn();
                                $(".eq_form").trigger('reset');
                            }

                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                        console.log('Error:', data);
                         }


                    });
```

Controller Code

```
           public function addQues(Request $request){

    print_r($request->all());
}
```

Response

```
       Array ( [_token] => ocEOwNjmhMEOLLPOuxuGUVLO8FItrqyAEYNDXSIA [ques] => question 2 data [opta] => ab [optb] => bc [optc] => cd [optd] => de )
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of your questions input name is same. Both are using `ques` that's why 2nd question is overriding 1st one.
You must have different names and pass two data to the ajax.

Comment: and how to retrieve in controller and save to db